# Load testing a ec2 Node.js machine - Now... how do I remotely load test 6500 QPS?

Tags: stress-testing, load-testing

Ok, I have my server built on ec2.  My stack is Nginx as a load balancer, supervisord for managing  processes for node.js i.e. one process for each cpu, and redis, master and slave on separate boxes.  I have stress tested by testing failover and taking services offline.  Using apache AB, on the server I can get up to 6500 QPS.

Now, I need to load test remotely.  What are the best open source tools to accomplish this or even the most cost effective SaaS method to do this.  I do expect 6500 QPS per server in production and need to extend the isolation of apache AB to remote testing.  E.g. I will have servers in singapore and I need to test 6500 QPS from Japan and the effect of latency.  I am aware of apache Jmeter but looking for a best practice solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully used [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for load testing at significant scale.

If a single load generation client cannot output enough load, you can configure jMeter with multiple load generation clients, with the load coordinated by a master instance.

Using "open source tools" implies that you have the ability to spin up servers in the zones you're interested in (e.g. Japan).  If you locate a cloud provider in that region, you can spin up as many load generation instances as needed.  You may, however, need quite a few instances depending on the network connectivity offered to individual instances.  The nice thing about jMeter is that it can coordinate many load generation instances.

Comment: Ah....so...e.g. create a master on ec2 and then e.g. boot say..15-20 mico instances? Or do I create a master on my local machine and have clients on ec2.

Comment: You can have the master and clients all on ec2. In fact, you almost certainly want the master on ec2 so that it can talk to the clients over a local network.  Be sure that you use the PRIVATE IP or PRIVATE DNS name of the clients so that you don't route control messages outside the AWS public router and back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [blazemeter](http://blazemeter.com) as SaaS solution. It's 100% Jmeter compatible. There is Japan(Tokyo) load origin location which you need.